# On what ISO/OSI layer does a hub operate?

Tags: ethernet, osi, hub, data-communication

In my studies we are right now learning about computer communication and i've gotten into a disagrement with my teacher whether a hub is operating on layer 1 or layer 2.

My understanding of a hub is that it is just a repeater with multiple outputs but looking at the exam we are gonna take the right answer of which layer a hub is on is always layer 2.

**Question:**
Since the internet pretty much unanimous agrees that a hub is operating on layer 1 I wonder what arguments can be made for it operating on layer 2.

[From our lecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVbAT.png)

[From our lecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ywalj.png)

Comment: I agree with you, but when I learned this stuff, a switch (clearly L2) was sometimes called a "switching hub". Possibly your teacher is equating "hub" to "switching hub" = "switch"? tbh I'm not sure how commonly you would find a "dumb" L1 hub in modern network infrastructure.

Comment: (The second slide you linked to seems to understand the difference between L2 switch and L1 hub, but the first slide kind of fudges them into "switch/hub".)

Comment: @slothrop, a repeater is technically a hub, otherwise you are right on spot that you use switches almost exclusively even for this purpose in modern infrastructure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hub is usually term for L1 device.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_hub) However, [L2 switch is sometimes called switching hub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch). Common terms for devices facilitating connection of multiple networked nodes on layers 1, 2 and 3 are:

- L1 (physical): a hub
- L2 (link): a switch
- L3 (network): a router

Comment: As you and @slothrop mentioned i think the "switching hub" may be the coulprit here, ty for taking time to answer.

Comment: Small addition: dual-speed hubs contain a bridge between their single-speed segments. A bridge operates at layer 2